# Floating images around text in a contenteditable div

Tags: image, css-float, contenteditable

I'm having some trouble floating images properly alongside text in a contenteditable div. Here's a fiddle which shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/tcLw2/10/

Would someone mind taking a look at the fiddle to provide some guidance on how to display the text alongside the image?

here's the HTML and CSS if you want to copy paste:

```
<p contenteditable="true" id="local"  >
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/26/YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg/260px-YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg"> sdfasfsfasfsfdasfsafasfajksf;asjf;as;jkasfk;as;lkfjaskfjkaslfjkasfkafl;sfklfjas;fjasjdfkasfkasfl;als;fjasf;slfjasfasfsadfasfasfafasfasfafsfddas
```

​
CSS:

```
p{background:yellow;}
img{float:left;}
```

Comment: Adding a `position: absolute;` to your `img` makes the text alongside

Comment: hi prajeesh, thanks that helps but now the text can be buried underneath the image. see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/tcLw2/13/ Is there any way to make it only wrap around the image?

Comment: Just move your `<img>` tag outside the paragraph and let it be the first http://jsfiddle.net/CQQk7/

Comment: Also there needs to be some whitespace in the text so that it can wrap.

Comment: Here is one nice tutorial about this http://www.tizag.com/cssT/float.php

Comment: hi prajeesh, thank you for all your help.  These are good facts to know. Is there any way to create a float effect with the img tag inside the paragraph?

Comment: I just saw that giving whitespaces in your long text in your original fiddle actually wraps it as you need :) It was only that your line was so long it couldn't be put alongside the image.

Comment: oh yeah, you are right! thanks again. I'll answer this question if you don't want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see Prajeesh's comments. He answers this question: "I just saw that giving whitespaces in your long text in your original fiddle actually wraps it as you need :) It was only that your line was so long it couldn't be put alongside the image"